# How to apply an external SetState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

Question: I have a React Component called "SignupForm" and I'm attemping to extend it as follows:

```
export default class UserSignup extends Component  {
    render() {
        const obForm = <SignupForm/>;
        obForm.setState({lockAccountType: true});
        return obForm;
    }
}
```

But this throws an error that the constant obForm lacks a setState method, `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: obForm.setState is not a function`

How should I go about setting the state of this react component then? I feel like thats the most proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to pass a prop down to SignupForm from UserSignup

`<SignupForm lockAccountType={Boolean} />`

In the SignupForm component, set the state with the lockAccountType prop. Most people do this with the componentDidMount life-cycle method. Give SignupForm an initial state of lockAccountType={Boolean} and then change it on componentDidMount with your prop.

Answer (score 0):

your parent component will contain state and child component will get state properties as in props. Parent component will have state change handler which is passed to child component as well. State will be changed in parent component so that setState will re-render new state every where.

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { name: 'Mike' }
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome {this.state.name}</h1>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleStateChange}  />

                <hr/>

                <Footer fName={this.state.name} changeProps={this.handleChangeProps}/>
            </div>
        )
    },
    handleStateChange: function(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    },
    handleChangeProps: function(name){
        console.log(name);
        this.setState({name: name})
    }
});


var Footer = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome {this.props.fName}</h1>
                <input type="text" value={this.props.fName} onChange={this.handlePropChange}/>
            </div>
        )
    },
    handlePropChange: function(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.props.changeProps(event.target.value);
    }
})



var pageElement = React.createElement(Header, {});

React.render(pageElement, document.getElementById('my-app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to echo some of the other answers while providing some more specific context for you.

#### UserSignup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SignupForm from './SignupForm';

export default class UserSignup extends Component  {
    render() {
        return (
            <SignupForm lockAccountType={true}/>
        );
    }
}
```

#### SignupForm.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class SignupForm extends Component  {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {lockAccountType: this.props.lockAccountType};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>
                {'lockAccountType: ' + this.state.lockAccountType}
            </Text>
        );
    }
}

SignupForm.propTypes = {
    lockAccountType: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};
```

(Feel free to modify `SignupForm.render()` obviously. This was just a proof-of-concept.)

As others mentioned, you want to pass down the `lockAccountType` value as a prop to the signup form.

In my example, that value is static (`true`). If you want that value to change, you would have it as a state variable in `UserSignup`:

#### UserSignup.js (Modified)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SignupForm from './SignupForm';

export default class UserSignup extends Component  {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {lockAccountType: true};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SignupForm lockAccountType={this.state.lockAccountType}/>
        );
    }
}
```

You'd probably want to add functionality that could adjust this state value. In general, any changes to your state will cause a re-render of that component. In this case, the changes would propagate to the `SignupForm` element and you should achieve your desired result.

A few final notes

- I'd advise to specify propTypes in your classes. When you are developing, this will warn you of any issues when you are assigning values to the props. In this example, we would see a warning if either `lockAccountType` is not specified or is the wrong type. If you remove the `.isRequired`, it would just warn you about wrong types.
- If you don't want to change the `lockAccountType` from within the `SignupForm` class directly, you can remove the constructor entirely and just use `this.props.lockAccountType` within that class. In that scenario, `SignupForm` would be a stateless class.

Hope this helps.